# android saxparser truncates xml tag content

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, saxparser

I am using saxparser in order to get xml tag contents from file. All works properly for a non long data xml. However, when arribed at certain position, characters() event received truncated ch[] and is triggered twice. For example for 1234567890 is received twice and value is truncated like following example. How to clear char array or memory?

```
id  1234567890
name myName1
id  1234567890
name myName2
...
(error)
id 1234567
id 890
name myName3
```

Code:

```
private StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(2048);

            @Override
            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {  

            if(this.v_Id){

                buf.append(ch, start, length);

                myParsedXMLDataSet.setId(buf.toString());

                Log.d("id", buf.toString());

                buf.delete(0, buf.length());

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`characters()` is allowed to be called multiple time for the same element ([see documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)). You should not assume that it will only be called once, even though most time that is the case. Append to the buffer each time `characters()` is called, then store the value when `endElement()` is called.